# Weblogic Message Driven Bean reading from a secured queue @RunAs does not work

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, weblogic, message-driven-bean

I have a MDB very simple which works fine as long as the queue from where it reads messages is not secured

After I secure the Queue with a username it can;t read messages anymore

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "DistributedQueueTest")

public class MdbReceiver implements MessageListener {
@Resource
private MessageDrivenContext mdc;

@Override
public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {
TextMessage msg = null;
try {
msg = (TextMessage) inMessage;
System.out.println("Test MdbReceiver Message received : " + msg.getText());
} catch (JMSException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
mdc.setRollbackOnly();
}
}

}
```

I tried with all kind of @RunAs annotations
`@weblogic.jws.security.RunAs(role="Joan",mapToPrincipal="ccc_user")` where ccc_user is alowed to read messages from the queue

import javax.annotation.security.RunAs;
`@RunAs("SomeRole")` gives me an error on deployment
Unable to deploy EJB: MdbReceiver from mdbReceiver.jar: Expected role in mapping

Any idea how can i do this with annotations ? I tried even without annotations
...same the exeption in weblogic console is

`weblogic.jms.common.JMSSecurityException: Access denied to resource: type=<jms>, application=UNIV_REC_Module, destinationType=queue, resource=DistributedQueueTest, action=receive`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you annotate your MDB as follows it should work:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "MdbReceiver", mappedName = "DistributedQueueTest")
@DeclareRoles({"Loan"})
@RolesAllowed("Loan")
public class MdbReceiver implements MessageListener {
...
}
```

Comment: Yes if you have the right version of weblogic , where they fixed some annotation related problems

Comment: The trick is in declaring roles to be employed in the MDB and in specifying which ones can be applied. I tried your code and also got an error, therefore in my opinion there's nothing to do with the version of WL, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I do not know what you tried exactly (how you tried).The solution from here works in some production environment already using an older weblogic.I was not able to make it work on 10.3 version using only annotations.Glad that you made it with annotations only so you don't have to use the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml and ejb-jar.xml BUT now you declare Roles and Authorizations in you code...not in some config file which might be ok if you do not change that very often.

Answer (score 2):

I answer to my question cause i found a solution :
The problem is that annotations or are buggy in weblogic or are not implemented as I expected.

Solution is to do this without annotations in old style

so MDB is:

```
public class MdbReceiver implements MessageListener ,MessageDrivenBean{

    MessageDrivenContext mdc;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {
        TextMessage msg = null;
        try {
            msg = (TextMessage) inMessage;
            System.out.println("qwerty1");
            System.out.println("Test MdbReceiver Message received : " + msg.getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mdc.setRollbackOnly();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void ejbRemove() throws EJBException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void setMessageDrivenContext(MessageDrivenContext mdc) throws EJBException {
        this.mdc = mdc;

    }
}
```

Then we need two other files:
ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>MdbReceiver</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>mdb.receiver.MdbReceiver</ejb-class>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
            <security-identity>
                <run-as>
                    <role-name>Loan</role-name>
                </run-as>
            </security-identity>
        </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
    <assembly-descriptor>       
         <security-role>
          <role-name>Loan</role-name>
         </security-role>       
        <container-transaction>
            <method>
                <ejb-name>MdbReceiver</ejb-name>
                <method-name>onMessage()</method-name>
            </method>
            <trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>
        </container-transaction>
    </assembly-descriptor>

</ejb-jar>
```

and

weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-ejb-jar version="wls_10.3"
    xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar" xmlns:j2ee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">
    <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
        <ejb-name>MdbReceiver</ejb-name>
        <message-driven-descriptor>
            <destination-jndi-name>DistributedQueueTest</destination-jndi-name>
        </message-driven-descriptor>
    </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <security-role-assignment>
        <role-name>Loan</role-name>     
        <principal-name>test1234</principal-name>
    </security-role-assignment>

</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

The role name does not matter as i can see the principal name is important.
It needs to have the rights to read from the secured queue